# How to style this type of class?

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-check">
```

It's a mark for check-sign. In a course that I'm doing the teacher had at that time just `class="fa-check"`. We were supposed to style it, to change the `color`, and I don't know how to do it.

I tried:

```
.plan li.fa-solid.fa-check

.plan li.fa-solid .fa-check

.fa-solid.fa-check
```

In the end, I just put style to the line and it worked but I know that this is not the recommended approach.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
i.fa-solid {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what you trying is called `css selector` [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Check the reference, it might help you get to sleep.

Suggestion: You haven't need to select specifically to your target element. If you working on simple project, just only your class's name. It's fine enough.

```
.fa-solid {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: It will change colour just of this check-sign? because this is what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

These icons come from the Font awesome icons library, and are styled in css. You'll want to identify the icon that you want to change the color of (ID and Class are useful for this) then add in a CSS rule for that designator.

This can be done on the same page, or in a separate stylesheet depending on what you are doing. Have at look at this link to learn more about how you can add color, size and other attributes to things in CSS. Understanding this concept early will be a great help to you in the future.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Also more information on the Font Awesome Icons:

https://www.infradox.com/working-with-font-awesome-icons/

Comment: Ok but please - tell me how to write it in styles? how to write this two classes and make it works? i want to change color of this check-sign.

Comment: Extending Paranaaan's answer, you can use the below. I've changed the selector to the fa-check class rather than fa-solid

.fa-check{
    color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro can u try this Method.

this is the fontawesome cdn link. u can use and link in your html head tag.

next use this icon it will 100% definitely works so try This....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).